# Convert query string parameter to entity

Tags: jsf, entity, converters, viewparams

I'm trying to do some of the most basic scenario i think.

On starting page there is a list of categories from database and after i click on category there should be a page with some details about that category (maybe print it name and some product etc.)

I was trying to do what [BalusC did on ther blog post](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ConvertingAndValidatingGETRequestParameters)

I'm using java-ee-7, glasfish 4.1, hibernate 4.3.5

in index.xhtml i make link to category with parameter:

```xml
<h:link outcome="category.xhtml" value="#{category.name}">
    <f:param name="categoryId" value="#{category.id}"/>
</h:link>
```

Categories are printed just fine with query string `categoryId` parameter.

Then on category.xhtml i have:

```xml
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="categoryId" 
        value="#{categoryController.category}"
        converter="#{categoryConverter}" />
</f:metadata>

<h:body>
    Category name:

    <h:outputText value="#{categoryController.category.name}" />
    <!-- this one prints nothing -->

</h:body>
```

CategoryController code looks like this:

```java
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class CategoryController {

    private Category category;

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
}
```

and the converter looks like this:

```java
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class CategoryConverter implements Converter {

    @Inject
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String s) {
        return categoryRepository.find(Integer.parseInt(s));
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object o) {
        if (o == null || !(o instanceof Category)) {
            return null;
        }
        return ((Category) o).getId().toString();
    }
}
```

Making some test only `getAsString` method is invoked, but i think there should be `getAsObject` instead.

Statement `<h:outputText value="#{categoryController.category.name}" />` prints nothing (it is probably null).
How can i have Category entity in `category.xhtml` page?

--

To make it clear, i make it work with somethink like

```xml
<h:commandButton action="#{categoryController.showCategory(category)}" />
```

but this generate `http post` and i want to have simple `get` request. For me it would be just ridiculous that it would be only accessible through `post`.

In case something is missing, i make it accessible through github with stripped unnecessary code here: https://github.com/Yavin/jsf-entity-convert

Comment: "*How to have `Category` entity accessible in category.xhtml page?*" You are accessing `private Category category;` through its accessor method here `<h:outputText value="#{categoryController.category.name}" />` on category.xhtml. What is the problem then?

Comment: @Tiny I updated question more preceisly. That statement (`<h:outputText ...`) prints nothing when i access `category.xhtml`. I think its because `categoryController.category` equal null and its not converted. After some debuging  only `getAsString` method is invoked with null `o` parameter.

Comment: The `getAsObject()` method in this case will never be invoked as obvious because you are merely outputting a String through an output component (`<h:outputText value="#{categoryController.category.name}"/>`). You are not submitting any string whose value is to be converted into an `Object` (the `Category` entity) by the said converter (`CategoryConverter`). You may need to do in the `getAsString()` method what you already did in the `getAsObject()` method in this particular case.

Comment: Which JSF impl/version are you using? Just stock GF4.1? Can't reproduce this with Mojarra 2.2.10. I also don't recognize this as one of known bugs.